# Convert time to double in ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a time parameter in SSRS report whose value is like "14:07:58". How can I convert it to double?

The data type of this parameter is string(text) and I want to convert this time to double.
I tried using `CDble("14:07:58")` but it returns error.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Why not convert it beforehand in the code (TSQL?) that returns the data to SSRS?  It's a string so can't be converted directly, certainly not in SRSS, you would need to split it into 3 strings, one for hours, one for mins and one for seconds, convert each of them to a number and calculate from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate "ticks" (100 nanoseconds) since midnight and divide it by the number of ticks per day:

```
=CDate("14:07:58").Ticks/TimeSpan.TicksPerDay
```